# Git won't add files - 'Permission denied'

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

Suddenly simple git functionality doesn't work.

When I'm trying to `git add`, I get the following error:

```
hudac@ubuntu:~/progg$ git add . --all
warning: unable to access 'dir1/dir2/.gitignore': Permission denied
```

I never created `dir1/dir2/.gitignore`.
This is strange:

```
hudac@ubuntu:~/progg$ ll dir1/dir2  
ls: cannot access dir1/dir2/..: Permission denied  
ls: cannot access dir1/dir2/.: Permission denied  
ls: cannot access dir1/dir2/file1: Permission denied  
total 0  
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ./  
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ../  
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file1
```

`file1` is the file that supposed to be under the path `dir1/dir2/file1`.

Is there a way to fix this?
It happened after I `chmod 644 -R dir1/dir*`

Comment: It doesn't matter, it was an example.
It happens also with just `git add .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made your files and **FOLDERS** within '*dir1*' have the 644 permissions when you ran that command which is the problem here.

Run this to reset the folder '*dir2*' to the correct permissions

```
chmod 755 dir1/dir2
```

[Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

Comment: Thanks, though, 
I couldn't understand why it happened if I changed the permission to 644?
Because `git` won't be able to write to this directories?

Comment: @hudac - That is absolutely correct. Generally in unix based systems 644 is standard file permission and 755 is standard directory permission. It does get alot more complicated though.